# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager When

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity, .net-core

I am getting

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager
>   1[Authorization.IdentityModels.ApplicationUser]' has been registered.

when I run my ApsCore MVC website.

this are segments from my code:

ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                        options.UseNpgsql(configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));



services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Configure:

```
app.UseIdentity();
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid>
```

ApplicationUser.cs

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
```

I will be very happy if you can help me.

Comment: Please post the code for the controller that is generating this exception.

Comment: The exception is not in a controller, it happens everywhere.

Answer (score 41):

Faced with the same issue after moving my Identity classes to Guid and found solution [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7856#issuecomment-394448300):

> You probably need to change your login partial view to use the new
>   user type IdentityUser

Within **`Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml`**, I just changed

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

To

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<MyUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<MyUser> UserManager
```

and that worked for me.

Comment: Fixed for me too, when moving away from GUIDs in the default `IdentityUser` to `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>`.

Comment: Here are two resources that explain how to do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio
That article references the sample code here: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/live/aspnetcore/security/authentication/add-user-data/sample/Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml

Answer (score 17):

Not sure if you are still seeing this issue, but here's some help for anyone else that stumbles upon this. (Note that the specifics are for version 1, but the need for an injected dependency not being available is the same.)

The issue is coming from some class in your application requiring a SignInManager in its constructor, but there isn't an implementation associated with it in the dependency injection setup.

To fix, in your Startup class, in the ConfigureServices method, register the SignInManager class in the services. For example:
    `services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>, SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();`

The AddIdentity extension method may have been updated since the original question was asked to add this in, but the same error type will show up for anything the IoC container can't resolve.

Comment: This didn't help for me in version 2.0. Here's what worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47563601/1443490

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I had added identity when i was creating the project which made it possible for the framework to inject  `UserManager<IdentityUser>` and `SignInManager<IdentityUser>` into my _loginPartial View. What i did was to change the `Type<TUser>` from `<IdentityUser>` to `<ApplicationUser>`(ApplicationUser is the identity class i want to use in the project which inherits from IdentityUser class) and everything works fine.