# Getting "Could not resolve a service of type .." after upgrading to Core 2 Preview 2

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I've just upgraded to ASP.NET Core 2 Preview 2 and ran into a problem with the depedency injection. I get

> Could not resolve a service of type
>   'LC.Tools.API.Data.GenericDbContext' for the parameter 'context' of
>   method 'Configure' on type 'LC.Tools.API.Startup'
>   when running the project.

I didn't have this problem when using the old version.

**DbContext (GenericDbContext):**

```
namespace LC.Tools.API.Data
{
    public class GenericDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public GenericDbContext(DbContextOptions<GenericDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            //Generic
            builder.Entity<Client>();
            builder.Entity<Graphic>();
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .

            //Shop
            builder.Entity<Models.Shop.Store>().ToTable("ShopClient");
            builder.Entity<Models.Shop.Category>().ToTable("ShopCategory");
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
namespace LC.Tools.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            this.HostingEnvironment = env;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddDbContext<Data.GenericDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(this.ConnectionString));

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, Data.GenericDbContext context)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
                {
                    ForwardedHeaders = Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor,
                    ForwardLimit = 2
                });

                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc();

            Data.Debug.Init.Initalize(context, env);
        }

        private IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; set; }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        private string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return this.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() ? Configuration.GetConnectionString("Development") : Configuration.GetConnectionString("Production");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

> An error occurred while starting the application.
>
> InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service
>   'LC.Tools.API.Data.GenericDbContext' from root provider.
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider) Exception: Could not
>   resolve a service of type 'LC.Tools.API.Data.GenericDbContext' for the
>   parameter 'context' of method 'Configure' on type
>   'LC.Tools.API.Startup'.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(object
>   instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
>
> ```
> InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service
>                     'LC.Tools.API.Data.GenericDbContext' from root provider.
> ```
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>       Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)
>       Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(object
>   instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180773/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-core-2-thows-exception

Comment: You are trying to inject the context into the `Configure` method which wont work. Remove the injected context from the `Configure` method and instead inject the service provider and try to resolve the context within the method.

Comment: I would also like to know what have changed in the last version since it worked in asp.net core 1. I'm just thinking it shouldn't be necessary with a custom implementation since it worked fine as it was.

Comment: As explained in the linked answer there are now only certain services that are available at startup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to inject the context into the `Configure` method which wont work. Remove the injected context from the `Configure` method and instead inject the service provider and try to resolve the context within the method.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddOptions();
    services.AddDbContext<Data.GenericDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(this.ConnectionString));

    services.AddMvc();

    // Build the intermediate service provider
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    //return the provider
    return serviceProvider;
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
    //...Other code removed for brevity

    var context = serviceProvider.GetService<Data.GenericDbContext>();
    Data.Debug.Init.Initalize(context, env);
}
```

Comment: You could have actually done everything in the `ConfigureServices` method instead of injecting into the `Configure` but that is your choice.

Comment: You don't need to build the service provider. I'm not sure why you're doing that actually.

Answer (score 2):

@Nkosi's answer got me on the right track but you don't actually need that many steps, at least in version 2.0 and up:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddOptions();
    services.AddDbContext<Data.GenericDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(this.ConnectionString));

    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
    //...Other code removed for brevity

    var context = serviceProvider.GetService<Data.GenericDbContext>();
    Data.Debug.Init.Initalize(context, env);
}
```

You don't need to return anything from `ConfigureServices` or build an intermediate provider in the version I'm running (2.0)